# Colocar aspas em um array - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso colocar dentro de cada elemento do meu array, aspas simples.

No código abaixo, verifico qual checkbox esta selecionado, e vou inserindo no meu array.

```
var checkbox = $('input:checkbox[name^=checkregiao]:checked');
            //verifica se existem checkbox selecionados
            if(checkbox.length > 0){
                //array para armazenar os valores
                var regioes_selecionadas = [];
                //função each para pegar os selecionados
                checkbox.each(function(){
                    regioes_selecionadas.push($(this).val());
                });
               alert(regioes_selecionadas);
             }
```

O meu alert, exibe: "SP,MG,RS,BA" desta forma.

Eu preciso que fique assim: "'SP','MG','RS','BA'". Vejam cada elemento está separado por aspas simples..

Consegui utilizar o comando:
var regioes_selecionadas = JSON.stringify(regioes_selecionadas);

Fica com aspas duplas.
"SP","MG","RS","BA"

Preciso aspas simples
"'SP','MG','RS','BA'"
Preciso aspas simples. Antes de postar aqui, pesquiso, procuro achar uma solução.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer imprimir uma string num formato específico, gere uma string, não um array que irá ser imprimido de formas diferentes dependendo do contexto.

Você pode começar adicionando as aspas nos próprios valores dos checkbox

```
regioes_selecionadas.push("'" + $(this).val() + "'");
```

Depois gere a string, separando os valores por virgula utilizando o método `join`:

```
var regioes_str = regioes_selecionadas.join(",");
alert(regioes_str);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela grande ajuda.